# Is "new face" a way to say a new person?

Tags: expressions

I'm french and in my language we use an expression whose naive english translation would be "new face", meaning a new person. Is it an actual thing I can say?

Comment: Yes, but note that in certain limited contexts "new face" refers to the result of plastic surgery.

Comment: There is a common (aged) expression that says "He's a new man", which needs some updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the expression is used in English:

[New face:](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/new-face)
(countable noun)

> Someone who is new in a particular public role can be referred to as a new face.
>
> - All together there are six new faces in the Cabinet. [+ in]

(Collins Dictionary )

Comment: '*I see lots of new faces here tonight*' (in a meeting)

Answer (score 0):

With **new faces**, well, sometimes, the “ordinariness” of an expression can be gauged by comparing it to something less ordinary.

For example, there’s the expression **new men, strange faces, other minds** from *La morte d’Arthur*,  https://www.bartleby.com/246/392.html

This expression was perhaps chosen by the poet to be noticeably different, but easily understood by the ordinary English speaker. In fact, with a literate audience you could possibly use the expression **strange faces and other minds** to imply the coming of new men in a way that was painful to the speaker.

In contrast, **new faces** is pretty conventional, as others have pointed out.